# Alternative to Breeze.js?

Tags: breeze

Is there an alternative to Breezejs that does not require .Net or Enterprise Framework Connector or database, and works with plain REST services that accept and return only JSON (no metadata)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We actually designed Breeze to be independent of .NET, but none of our samples show this yet. In the next week or two we will show how to connect Breeze to a generic HTTP service that returns JSON. We'd love to have your feedback on this when it comes out, as we know it will be a big part of the market.

**Edit:** Breeze 1.3.0 is now available and contains the [Edmunds sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/edmunds), which is a pure JavaScript client that connects to an HTTP service with **no** dependencies on ASP.NET, Web API, or the Entity Framework. Please take a look and provide us with feedback!

**Edit 2:** We will also be releasing a sample soon that shows Breeze working with MongoDB, Express, and Node.js with no Microsoft technologies involved. A Ruby sample is also in the works. Stay tuned!

**Edit 3:** [MongoDB and node.js support](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb) is now available which shows Breeze working with the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js).

**Edit 4:** A [Ruby sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/intro-spa-ruby) is now up. This is John Papa's famous Code Camper JumpStart with a Ruby back-end.

**Edit 5:** [NHibernate support](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/nhibernate-support) as well as an accompanying sample are now available.

**Edit 6:** [Node/MySQL/Postgres support](http://www.getbreezenow.com/sequelize-mysqlpostgressql-lite) as well as an accompanying sample are now available.

**Edit 7:** [Java/Hibernate support](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.java) as well as an accompanying sample are now available.

Comment: Happy to give feedback when the examples are available.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I'll let you know when it becomes available.

Comment: @Steve - Ok, the sample is out. You can download it as part of the Breeze samples package: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download

Comment: @Ting When breeze is independent of .NET how does the re-use of server side validation attributes also work for example for java models?

Comment: Breeze metadata which can be provided either from the server or the client may include any number of "validators" on each property of an entity as well as on the entity itself.  From a serialization perspective a "validator" consists of a "name" and a collection of constructor parameters.  Breeze converts these validator descriptions into actual validators on the client by looking for a "registered" validator (see the Validator.register and Validator.registerFactory methods) and then instantiating it with the specified constructor parameters.  Not sure how clear this is, but...

Comment: Please add a separate question on non-net validation if the above description was not sufficient.

Comment: I've posted a question closely related to what is disussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181567/breezejs-on-durandal-with-php-rest-api-laravel

Comment: Any plan to add a sample for using Browse with Google Appengine (Python) backend?

Comment: With due respects, @jay-traband, please let us know if breezejs is still a viable candidate for use as a client side complement to the Entity Framework Core. I liked its ability to cache, query, track data and state just like we use EF Core for a Server Side framework? We wanted the ability to use something like this in the .NET5 domain for a production grade application that will have high demands on performance.

Answer (score 7):

[Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) has a JavaScript ORM that's very similar to Breeze.js. It's called [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline).

Comment: I this this is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

JayData http://jaydata.org/  would be an alternative to Breeze that is independent of .NET as well. Another alternative you could look at is ember.data  https://github.com/emberjs/data FYI I have looked at both and prefer Breeze for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

For alternative there is [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/), [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/), and [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) each comes with its own pros/cons.